F-score, precision and recall metrics for a penalized logistic regression
I'm trying to do crossvalidation for a penalized logistic regression model that I made.
I'm also noticing that some examples on the internet assume that I'm just going manally type in arrays of actual and predicted numbers from a full dataset (who has time for that lol?).
I was using JuliusAI because it reports this stuff out of the box but went back to R because I now don't trust the reproduceability of Julius (for full disclosure), and stopped using it, despite the lure of push-button analysis. I want to be able to compute these metrics on my own faithfully and am new to using crossvalidation in R (normally have done AIC and significance stats). But enough about JuliusAI.
Here's the problem. I have a dataset (n=32) that I used an 80/20 split to train and test. That part is fine. My predictor variable is binary. The train data set is called train (25 rows), and the test is called test (has 7 rows). The penalized logistic regression model has 3 predictor variables, and the outcome is either fail or not fail. The regression procedure works fine so I added the confusion matrix to get what I need.
I've been trying to use the ConfusionMatrix command and I keep getting
Error in Confusion Matrix : the data and reference factors must have the same number of levels

This is what I used:
library(rsample)
library(caret)
library(logistf)
split <- initial_split(newdata1, prop = .8)
train <- training(split)
test  <- testing(split)
fit <- logistf(data=train, newdata1$`Fail (1=yes)`~ 
newdata1$`rev`+newdata1$`totassets`+newdata1$`totliab`)
prediction <- predict(fit, data = test, type = 'response')
pred <- factor(ifelse(prediction <= 0.5,0,1))
result <- caret::confusionMatrix(pred,test$`Fail (1=yes)`)

So then I tried:
cm <- confusionMatrix(pred, as.factor(test$`Fail (1=yes)`)

And got
Error in confusionMatrix.default(pred, as.factor(test$`Fail (1=yes)`)) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference"
confusionMatrix(pred,as.factor(test$`Fail (1=yes)`))
Error in confusionMatrix.default(pred, as.factor(test$`Fail (1=yes)`)) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Is there a more straightforward way to do this and get the metrics? I thought there was a F1 score command but it seems that this expects a y_pred and I don't see how to generate or access this (except through predict()).
Could it be because I the data set has 10 variables and I'm using 3 of them or is it because of the split? How do I address this?
Your suggestions?

My guess is it's because of the split. Maybe 1) coerce the data column to factor, test$`Fail (1=yes)` <- as.factor(test$`Fail (1=yes)`); then assign levels(pred) <- levels(test$`Fail (1=yes)`) . Like this both vectors have the same levels and the error might go away. But without the data it's hard to tell.

Hi Rui, thanks for your reply. Tried your suggestion but received: Error in confusionMatrix.default(pred, as.factor(test$Fail (1=yes))) :
there must be at least 2 factors levels in the data

In your validation set how many passed and how many  fails?  I am thinking either your validation group or the predictions are all one sided and not balanced.  Also do you think you can get a good 3 variable model and only 25 rows of data?

Hi Dave2e, yes, the dataset is not balanced but only has 32 observations. Each row of the dataset represents a year of operation of a company. If they haven't failed yet, the outcome variable is 0. If they finally go out of business, it's 1. So there's more zeroes than ones. I'm trying to crossvalidate it so training with an 80-20 split is how we end up with the 25/7 split. I tried SMOTE on JuliusAI but because I'm writing a paper, I don't feel confident that others can replicate the results in R, so I abandoned using SMOTE because it just seemed so janky.
